# Usage of FOR UPDATE in window function - Postgres

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql

I'm working on Oracle to Postgres migration, The service is using **my-batis** for the DB connection, and have some complex queries that I couldn't convert with some reference.

Below is the table definition of which the query is to run.

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1(
   NOTIFY_ID                   bigint    primary key        not null,
   TRANSACTION_ID              numeric                      not null,
   EVENT_TYPE                  character varying(64)        not null,
   EVENT_TIME                  timestamp(6) with time zone  not null,
   SOURCE_TRANSACTION_ID       numeric,
   QUANTITY                    numeric,
   PROCESSED                   character varying(8)         not null,
   CURRENCY_CODE               character varying(8),
   COST                        numeric(12,2),
   DESTINATION_LOCATION        character varying(32),
   SOURCE_LOCATION             character varying(32),
   CUSTOMER_COUNTRY_CODE       character varying(2)
);
```

Here is the Oracle query which needs to be converted to PostgreSQL.

```
SELECT
    TRANSACTION_ID,
    EVENT_TYPE,
    EVENT_TIME,
    CUSTOMER_COUNTRY_CODE,
    SOURCE_TRANSACTION_ID,
    PROCESSED,
    QUANTITY,
    CURRENCY_CODE,
    COST,
    TABLE1.NOTIFY_ID,
    DESTINATION_LOCATION,
    SOURCE_LOCATION
FROM
  (SELECT
    NOTIFY_ID, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY TRANSACTION_ID, NOTIFY_ID) AS RANK
  FROM
    table1
  WHERE
    PROCESSED = 'FALSE' ) RANKED
  INNER JOIN
    TABLE1
  ON RANKED.NOTIFY_ID = table1.NOTIFY_ID
WHERE
  RANK  <= 5
ORDER BY TRANSACTION_ID
FOR UPDATE OF TABLE1.NOTIFY_ID
SKIP LOCKED
```

When I run this query by removing the column name after for update it says `"FOR UPDATE is not allowed with window functions."` I'm not sure how to convert this query to Postgresql compatible.

Please help me in converting this query.

Thanks,
Gokul.

Comment: IMHO the `SKIP LOCKED` part is Oracle's proprietary extension.

Comment: This is part of code that includes an update.    You need to understand everything the code does in order to port it.

Comment: Try to extract the subquery with the window functions to a `WITH` expression. Maybe that helps.

Comment: from my experience, this looks like the code is written so that multiple threads can run concurrently -- using the select for update will lock rows so that the other session will skip those.  I don't know postgres but there must be some way to do a similar thing.  One thing you could consider would be to use a "MOD" function to separate the rows and make sure the threads don't overwrite each other (not sure if that would work).  But I would be careful before removing that for update clause

Comment: This code does Oracle Advanced queuing without  "Advanced queuing". So multiple connections can lock a withdraw some rows, from table and updated them as processed. https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/what-is-select-skip-locked-for-in-postgresql-9-5/

Comment: @ibre5041 " IMHO the SKIP LOCKED part is Oracle's proprietary extension. " PostgreSQL supports `SKIP LOCKED` at least since 9.5 (released 2016-01-07), see E.26.3.3 at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/release-9-5.html